# Is it possible to have isolated networks in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cluster-computing, istio

I'm trying to set up a general architecture for a system that I'm moving to Kubernetes (self-hosted, probably on VSphere).

I'm not very well versed in networking and I have the following problem that I cannot seem to be able to conceptually solve:

I have many microservices which were split out of a monolith, but the monolith is still significant. All of it is moving to K8s. It's a clustered application and does a lot of all-to-all networking under high load, which I would like to separate from all the other services in the Kubernetes cluster.

Before moving to K8s we provided a way to specify a network device that is used only for the cluster communication, and as such could be strictly separated from other traffic, and alas, even use separate networking hardware for clustering.

So this is where I would request your input: is it possible to have completely separate networking for this application-level cluster inside the Kubernetes cluster? The ideal solution would allow me to continue using our existing logic, i.e. to have a separate network (and network adapter) for the chatty bits but it's not a hard requirement to keep it that way. I have looked at `Calico`, `Flannel`, and `Istio`, but haven't been able to come up with a sound concept.

Answer (score 1):

Use k8s NetworkPolicies, by applying these policing, you can allow/deny traffic for pods base on label selector. you can try WeaveNet and Calico, both are good and support NetworkPolicies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've reviewed NetworkPolicies, however, I need to restrict just certain parts of the traffic while allowing others. The same application should send cluster packets only to cluster members but all other traffic to other microservices should be unrestricted.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have Calico network plugin. Because Flannel doesn't support network policies. You can create NetworkPolicies resources for allow/deny the traffics.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle the requirements using Calico, could you give an example?  The same application should send cluster packets only to cluster members but all other traffic to other microservices should be unrestricted.

Answer (score 0):

On OpenShift, you can have an isolated network per project (Kubernetes namespace). See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#isolating-project-networks

Comment: This looks promising, thank you for pointing it out, but I think we need to steer clear of building a system that only works on OpenShift.

Comment: I wonder why? OpenShift can run on several public clouds and on bare metal as well. (Disclosure: I am an IBM employee).

Comment: We have clients that already have other solutions and/or don't want to migrate to OpenShift.